# Google docs spreadsheet script error OAuthConfig when fetching data from Fitbit

Tags: google-sheets, authorization, fetch, fitbit

I have got following script in Google docs spreadsheet which is fetching data from Fitbit. Script worked fine so far but recently on 6th July Google stopped using **OAuthConfig** so script is not working since:-(

I am not programmer, I am just advanced user. So I would like to kindly ask  some programmer to help tune script below in order to make it work again.

```
// Key of ScriptProperty for Firtbit consumer key.
var CONSUMER_KEY_PROPERTY_NAME = "fitbitConsumerKey";
// Key of ScriptProperty for Fitbit consumer secret.
var CONSUMER_SECRET_PROPERTY_NAME = "fitbitConsumerSecret";
// Default loggable resources (from Fitbit API docs).
var LOGGABLES = ["activities/log/steps", "activities/log/distance",
    "activities/log/activeScore", "activities/log/activityCalories",
    "activities/log/calories", "foods/log/caloriesIn",
    "activities/log/minutesSedentary",
    "activities/log/minutesLightlyActive",
    "activities/log/minutesFairlyActive",
    "activities/log/minutesVeryActive", "sleep/timeInBed",
    "sleep/minutesAsleep", "sleep/minutesAwake", "sleep/awakeningsCount",
    "body/weight", "body/bmi", "body/fat",];

// function authorize() makes a call to the Fitbit API to fetch the user profile    
function authorize() {
    var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("fitbit");
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token");
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token");
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/authorize");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey(getConsumerKey());
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(getConsumerSecret());
    var options = {
        "oAuthServiceName": "fitbit",
        "oAuthUseToken": "always",
    };
    // get the profile to force authentication
    Logger.log("Function authorize() is attempting a fetch...");
    try {
       var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/profile.json", options);
       var o = Utilities.jsonParse(result.getContentText());
       return o.user;
    }
    catch (exception) {
       Logger.log(exception);
       Browser.msgBox("Error attempting authorization");
       return null;
    }
}

// function setup accepts and stores the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, firstDate, and list of Data Elements
function setup() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Setup Fitbit Download");
    app.setStyleAttribute("padding", "10px");

    var consumerKeyLabel = app.createLabel("Fitbit OAuth Consumer Key:*");
    var consumerKey = app.createTextBox();
    consumerKey.setName("consumerKey");
    consumerKey.setWidth("100%");
    consumerKey.setText(getConsumerKey());
    var consumerSecretLabel = app.createLabel("Fitbit OAuth Consumer Secret:*");
    var consumerSecret = app.createTextBox();
    consumerSecret.setName("consumerSecret");
    consumerSecret.setWidth("100%");
    consumerSecret.setText(getConsumerSecret());
    var firstDate = app.createTextBox().setId("firstDate").setName("firstDate");
    firstDate.setName("firstDate");
    firstDate.setWidth("100%");
    firstDate.setText(getFirstDate());

    // add listbox to select data elements
    var loggables = app.createListBox(true).setId("loggables").setName(
      "loggables");
    loggables.setVisibleItemCount(4);
    // add all possible elements (in array LOGGABLES)
    var logIndex = 0;
    for (var resource in LOGGABLES) {
        loggables.addItem(LOGGABLES[resource]);
        // check if this resource is in the getLoggables list
        if (getLoggables().indexOf(LOGGABLES[resource]) > -1) {
          // if so, pre-select it
          loggables.setItemSelected(logIndex, true);
        }
        logIndex++;
    }
    // create the save handler and button
    var saveHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("saveSetup");
    var saveButton = app.createButton("Save Setup", saveHandler);

    // put the controls in a grid
    var listPanel = app.createGrid(6, 3);
    listPanel.setWidget(1, 0, consumerKeyLabel);
    listPanel.setWidget(1, 1, consumerKey);
    listPanel.setWidget(2, 0, consumerSecretLabel);
    listPanel.setWidget(2, 1, consumerSecret);
    listPanel.setWidget(3, 0, app.createLabel(" * (obtain these at dev.fitbit.com)"));
    listPanel.setWidget(4, 0, app.createLabel("Start Date for download (yyyy-mm-dd)"));
    listPanel.setWidget(4, 1, firstDate);
    listPanel.setWidget(5, 0, app.createLabel("Data Elements to download:"));
    listPanel.setWidget(5, 1, loggables);

    // Ensure that all controls in the grid are handled
    saveHandler.addCallbackElement(listPanel);
    // Build a FlowPanel, adding the grid and the save button
    var dialogPanel = app.createFlowPanel();
    dialogPanel.add(listPanel);
    dialogPanel.add(saveButton);
    app.add(dialogPanel);
    doc.show(app);
}

// function sync() is called to download all desired data from Fitbit API to the spreadsheet                 
function sync() {
    // if the user has never performed setup, do it now
    if (!isConfigured()) {
        setup();
        return;
    }

    var user = authorize();
    // Spatny kod, oprava nize - var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pavel');
    doc.setFrozenRows(1);
    var options = {
        "oAuthServiceName": "fitbit",
        "oAuthUseToken": "always",
        "method": "GET"
    };
    // prepare and format today's date, and a list of desired data elements
    var dateString = formatToday();
    var activities = getLoggables();
    // for each data element, fetch a list beginning from the firstDate, ending with today
    for (var activity in activities) {
        var currentActivity = activities[activity];
        try {
            var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/"
          + currentActivity + "/date/" + getFirstDate() + "/"
          + dateString + ".json", options);
        } catch (exception) {
            Logger.log(exception);
            Browser.msgBox("Error downloading " + currentActivity);
        }
        var o = Utilities.jsonParse(result.getContentText());

        // set title
        var titleCell = doc.getRange("a1");
        titleCell.setValue("date");
        var cell = doc.getRange('a2');

        // fill the spreadsheet with the data
        var index = 0;
        for (var i in o) {
            // set title for this column
            var title = i.substring(i.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
            titleCell.offset(0, 1 + activity * 1.0).setValue(title);

            var row = o[i];
            for (var j in row) {
                var val = row[j];
                cell.offset(index, 0).setValue(val["dateTime"]);
                // set the date index
                cell.offset(index, 1 + activity * 1.0).setValue(val["value"]);
                // set the value index index
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}

function isConfigured() {
    return getConsumerKey() != "" && getConsumerSecret() != "";
}

function setConsumerKey(key) {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty(CONSUMER_KEY_PROPERTY_NAME, key);
}

function getConsumerKey() {
    var key = ScriptProperties.getProperty(CONSUMER_KEY_PROPERTY_NAME);
    if (key == null) {
        key = "";
    }
    return key;
}

function setLoggables(loggable) {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("loggables", loggable);
}

function getLoggables() {
    var loggable = ScriptProperties.getProperty("loggables");
    if (loggable == null) {
        loggable = LOGGABLES;
    } else {
        loggable = loggable.split(',');
    }
    return loggable;
}

function setFirstDate(firstDate) {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty("firstDate", firstDate);
}

function getFirstDate() {
    var firstDate = ScriptProperties.getProperty("firstDate");
    if (firstDate == null) {
        firstDate = "2012-01-01";
    }
    return firstDate;
}

function formatToday() {
    var todayDate = new Date;
    return todayDate.getFullYear()
    + '-'
    + ("00" + (todayDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
    + '-'
    + ("00" + todayDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
}

function setConsumerSecret(secret) {
    ScriptProperties.setProperty(CONSUMER_SECRET_PROPERTY_NAME, secret);
}

function getConsumerSecret() {
    var secret = ScriptProperties.getProperty(CONSUMER_SECRET_PROPERTY_NAME);
    if (secret == null) {
        secret = "";
    }
    return secret;
}

// function saveSetup saves the setup params from the UI
function saveSetup(e) {
    setConsumerKey(e.parameter.consumerKey);
    setConsumerSecret(e.parameter.consumerSecret);
    setLoggables(e.parameter.loggables);
    setFirstDate(e.parameter.firstDate);
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    app.close();
    return app;
}

// function onOpen is called when the spreadsheet is opened; adds the Fitbit menu
function onOpen() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var menuEntries = [{
        name: "Sync",
        functionName: "sync"
    }, {
        name: "Setup",
        functionName: "setup"
    }, {
        name: "Authorize",
        functionName: "authorize"
    }];
    ss.addMenu("Fitbit", menuEntries);
}

// function onInstall is called when the script is installed (obsolete?)
function onInstall() {
    onOpen();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with updated code at https://github.com/loghound/Fitbit-for-Google-App-Script